# How can I give Unity camera permission in MacOS?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to make an **AR** app by using Unity in combination with **Vuforia** for my school project. When I want to run the app in Unity and try it out without building it to my phone, Unity crashes.

As far as I've seen through researching this issue, many people experience the same problem. It seems the issue has to do with the camera permissions on Mac.

I'm desperate in finding a fix for this. Any help at all is very much appreciated!

I'm running osx version **10.15.4**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was fixed in Unity 2019.3, what version are you using? Check this page out for some more info, and some solutions posted by others:

[enter link description here](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/osx-unity-fails-to-ask-camera-permission-and-crashes-on-privacy-violation)